# Twitter api 1.1 error 32 then sending direct messages

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I try to send a direct message  using twitter api version 1.1. For request building I use last version of Ricardo Pereira TwitterOAuth library from  https://github.com/ricardoper/TwitterOAuth. My application has read write and direct messages permissions, users are following each other but I keep getting error code 32(Could not autentificate you). I'm able to get current user credentials and friends list but not able to send messages... Do you have any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in parameters sent to twitter api - I had a space after user_id parameter.